# API call to external system to pull data to marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, ssjs

Is it possible to make an API call from the marketing cloud to pull data from external system? One way to do it create a script activity and schedule it or calling the activity through API. Real question is can you make it real time from marketing cloud

Answer (score 0):

You answered yourself there. The near real time option would be a call to the activity through API, or if that is applicable: in journey builder you could build a custom activity to pull the data in when a subscriber hits the activity in JB.